# Blender was running fast then randomly became extremely slow to open

Tags: gpu, error, performance

I had left a blender file running for a couple days in the backround and went to open it and it wouldn't pop up, so i ended the task. When i went to open blender again it took 5 minutes to open and usually it opens instantly. Then when it finally opened it took several more minutes after pressing open file, which is also usually instantaneous.

I uninstalled and reinstalled all the the blender in the DL section and it was the same issue with every iteration of blender. I then did a clean reinstall of my gpu drivers. Then Did a Clean reinstall of blender and it is the same issue

[image]

Comment: Could you still have an old process from the session you previously killed taking up system resources? Check in Task Manager that you have nothing unexpected taking up CPU, Memory or Disk activity. Try a full reboot by right-clicking the start button and selecting Reboot (after ensuring to save all your work first).

Comment: not really a fix but i ended up reformatting my laptop and blender is running fine now thank y'all for tryna help